# Where to put the php code in the php script below

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a javascript variable below where it is suppose to retrieve  `$_SESSION['imagename']` from imageupload.php (a seperate page)

```
var imagename = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_SESSION['imagename']) ? $_SESSION['imagename'] : null); ?>;
```

But what my question is where do I put this code below in the php script so that the session variable contains the name of the files and be able to be retrieve by the variable above?

```
if (isset($_POST['fileImage'])) { // fileImage is the name of the file input
  $_SESSION['imagename'] =  $_FILES['fileImage']['name'];
}

$_SESSION['fileImage']['name'] = $_FILES['fileImage']['name'];
```

Below is the php script:

```
$result = 0;

if( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) {  

    $parts = explode(".",$_FILES['fileImage']['name']);
    $ext = array_pop($parts);
    $base = implode(".",$parts);
    $n = 2;

    while( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$base."_".$n.".".$ext)) $n++;
    $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] = $base."_".$n.".".$ext;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"], 
    "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
    $result = 1;

}
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
      "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
      $result = 1;


      }

?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo "'$result'";?>); // call backs javascript function
</script>
```

Comment: This code will also allow someone to upload php files, perhaps you dont want that.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I will change it to make it safe after this issue can be solved :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $result = 0;

    if (isset($_POST['fileImage']) && ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000))){
          //you must check for file type, else your website could be hacked.
       if( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) { 
          //... 
       }
       else{
          //...
       }
    }

    $_SESSION['fileImage']['name'] = $_FILES['fileImage']['name'];
```

Comment: does the javascript function go at the bottom or in between the brackets?

Comment: bottom. $result is defined outside the brackets, so it should work.